# Проверка и обращение к свойству неизвестного объекта

Tags: .net, vb.net, рефлексия

Как организовать обращение к свойству объекта?

Например, мой класс является потребителем объекта чужого класса, структура которого неизвестна, и ему требуется проверить, существует ли у используемого объекта свойство с определенным именем, определить тип, и как по имени обратиться к этому свойству.

Имя свойства тоже неизвестно заранее и может быть сгенерировано.

Comment: Хм. Вам хочется странного, вы что-то делаете не так. Вам не должно хотеться работать с объектом неизвестного типа. Расскажите, какая ваша _настоящая_ задача.

Comment: (Хотя технически это возможно, через рефлексию.)

Comment: Задача - в классе есть метод, один из входных параметров объект типа Object :) дженерик в общем. Что передадут в этот метод неизвестно. Мне необходимо как-то проверить есть ли у объекта ряд свойств с определенным типом и именем. и Если есть получить значение для дальнейшей обработки. Имя свойств тоже не 100% известно.

Comment: Не, а откуда такая задача? Для чего всё это затеяно? Наверняка можно сделать по-другому и правильнее.

Comment: Обработка пользовательских скриптов для расчетов в ИС. То-есть рефлексия

Comment: Для представления скриптовых объектов вам нужен, понятно, какой-нибудь `ExpandoObject` или что-то наподобие, у чего можно опросить список методов. (Я не знаю, что такое ИС.)

Comment: ИС - информационная система, за ExpandoObject  спасибо сейчас изучу

Comment: @Артем в C# есть отличный механизм для выполнения кода на лету - [Scripting API](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples). Прикрутить его гораздо проще, чем писать собственный парсер, и разбирать каждое обращение к свойству.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У объекта можно получить его тип вызвав GetType(), и получить список методов, полей, свойств вызвав GetMembers().

```
void Test(object o) {
  foreach (var m in o.GetType().GetMembers())
     Console.WriteLine(m.MemberType + "\t" + m.Name + ":" + m.ReflectedType.Name);
}

Test(1);
```

Результат

```
Method  CompareTo:Int32
Method  CompareTo:Int32
Method  Equals:Int32
Method  Equals:Int32
Method  GetHashCode:Int32
Method  ToString:Int32
Method  ToString:Int32
Method  ToString:Int32
Method  ToString:Int32
Method  Parse:Int32
Method  Parse:Int32
Method  Parse:Int32
Method  Parse:Int32
Method  TryParse:Int32
Method  TryParse:Int32
Method  GetTypeCode:Int32
Method  GetType:Int32
Field   MaxValue:Int32
Field   MinValue:Int32
```

---

Чтобы вызвать метод с определенным типом параметров:

```
var res = o.GetType()
           .GetMethod("CompareTo", new [] { typeof(string) })
           .Invoke(o, new [] { "12345" });   // вызвать String.CompareTo(String)
```

Чтобы получить значение свойства:

```
var o = (object)"12345"; // (object) для примера, чтобы 'спрятать' информацию о типе String
var res = o.GetType().GetProperty("Length").GetValue(o);
```

---

**UPDATE**

Отвечаю на вопросы из комментариев от Grundy и Qwertiy.

Вопрос: *"Что за любовь к var'ам?"*
Ответ: `var s = "12345";` короче чем `string s = "12345";`

Вопрос: *"а зачем было var o = (object) "12345";?"*
Ответ: в вопросе сказано, что в метод "моего класса" передается "объект чужого класса, структура которого неизвестна", т.е. в метод передается object и надо по имени свойства объекта получить значение.
В такой ситуации в "моем классе" надо определить метод:

```
object GetPropValue(object o, string propName) {
   return o.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(o);
}

var s = "12345";            // это "объект чужого класса" 
var res = GetPropValue(s, "Length");  // s передается как object
```

Смысл того, что происходит можно коротко записать так:

```
var o = (object)"12345";  // (object) для примера, чтобы 'спрятать' информацию о типе
var res = o.GetType().GetProperty("Length").GetValue(o);
```

Comment: а зачем было `var o = (object) "12345";`?

Comment: @Grundy _"а зачем было var o = (object) "12345";?"_ -- это для примера. чтобы "спрятать" информацио о типе String. а вообще можно определи метод `T GetValue<T>(object o, string propName) { return (T) o.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(o); }`

Comment: Что за любовь к var'ам? `var o = (object)"12345";` => `object o = "12345";`

Comment: @Qwertiy _"var o = (object)"12345"; => object o = "12345";"_ -- приведение к object нужно было для примера -- чтобы показать, что в коде была, например, строка, а затем ее передали в метод как object.

Comment: Оба варианта делают приведение к object. Но один использует object для объявления переменной, а другой делает сначала явное приведение, а потом из его результата неявно достаёт тип object. Чем второе лучше?

Comment: @Qwertiy  _"Чем второе лучше?"_  -- если не знаете, то задайте отдельный вопрос. а про `(object)"12345"` я уже и вам говорил и [выше](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488695/#comment572163_488716). и в ответе есть комментарий.